# SlidingListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity, sliding

Can anyone provide an example how the SlidingMenu - many thanks to Jeremy Feinstein for developing such a great library - can be enabled with a ListActivity?

If I have a FragmentActivity I can set the content of the SlidingMenu:

```
setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
mFrag = new SampleListFragment();
t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
t.commit();
```

But this is not possible with `ListActivity` because I have no access to `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend a Fragment class from the Support Library, like ListFragment or FragmentActivity, to use the FragmentManager.

For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```